# Volatility of accessing shared memory across requests in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core

[Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) mentioned in [this blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/12/can-i-skip-the-lock-when-reading-an-integer/) several years ago that:

> The C# compiler, JIT compiler and CPU are all permitted to make optimizations provided that the optimization is undetectable by the current thread. In particular, reads and writes of variables may be re-ordered or eliminated entirely provided that doing so is not observable to the current thread.

What that means is that the following program could legally enter an infinite loop, because the mutation to `x` is never observed by the main thread (and in fact, on .NET 6, this indeed happens under Release build on my machine):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int z = 0;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            x = 1;
        });

        while (x == 0)
            unchecked { z = z + 1; }
    }
}
```

Now I wonder in a server application like ASP.NET Core that inherently supports concurrency and is multi-threaded, such compiler reordering/register caching or whatever behind-the-scene optimizations could lead to subtle bugs? For example, assume I have a singleton service like this that is accessed concurrently as the server processes requests:

```
public class SingletonService
{
    private string _cachedValue;

    public async Task<string> GetStringValue()
    {
        if (IsValueExpired(_cachedValue))
        {
            _cachedValue = await GetNewValue();
        }
        return _cachedValue;
    }

    ...
}

// when configuring the DI services, e.g. in Startup.cs
services.AddSingleton<SingletonService>;
```

Is it possible for the mutation to `_cachedValue` to be *never observed* by a request-processing thread, even *long* after the value has been updated by another thread? If this is true, it means that this kind of caching is prone to subtle and hard-to-reproduce bugs, and I'll probably need to wrap the read/write of `_cachedValue` in locks (which I understand provides memory barriers which will ensure that the mutations are flushed to all threads).

Specifically I would like to know if the comment by Eric above is still correct or relevant in .NET Core/.NET 5+ and the async/await world today? And if so, what's the best approach to caching this kind of things in memory in ASP.NET Core? Do I need to wrap all shared memory access in locks just to be safe?

P.S. I understand the difference between "multi-tasking" and "multi-threading", and that the request processing pipeline in ASP.NET Core is fully asynchronous and not tied to a specific thread. But this is not relevant for the question above so forgive me for using the term "multi-threading" a bit loosely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible for the mutation to _cachedValue to be never observed by a request-processing thread, even long after the value has been updated by another thread?

Possible, but highly unlikely. If the request thread runs just about anything other than a loop checking the value it is very likely going to issue a load of the value sooner or later.

> I'll probably need to wrap the read/write of _cachedValue in locks

I believe `volatile` should be sufficient for this specific case, but as Eric lippert mentions, locks are in general safer and easier to understand than volatile.

> Do I need to wrap all shared memory access in locks just to be safe?

It is in general a good idea to use locks whenever shared memory access is involved. My rule of thumb is: "if in doubt, use a lock". Just make sure to avoid deadlocks. An uncontested lock takes about 25ns to take, so you would likely have to service a huge amount of requests before this becomes an issue, assuming you only need to hold the lock for a brief time.

But for caching there is builtin [memory cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-7.0) that I would presume are thread safe. There are also classes like [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-8.0) that might be appropriate for a multi threaded caching scenario. Or [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-8.0) that can be used for caching values, and is optionally thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I figured it's good practice to actively ensure volatility instead of leaving it to luck. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good answer; I would strengthen your advice to use locks, not volatile. Volatile is a sharp tool for experts who know how, when and why to use it. My rule of thumb is that if the solution to the puzzle linked below is not *immediately obvious* to you, then you (like me!) don't understand volatile well enough to use it safely. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/26/reordering-optimizations/

Comment: @scharnyw: The most important advice in this answer is to *use off the shelf parts rather than inventing your own*. If you want a lazily initialized threadsafe singleton, the experts at Microsoft already wrote a correct, high performance one for you in `Lazy<T>`.  Don't waste time and effort making a wrong, slow version of their work.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks Eric for the comments! Advice well taken (which goes along with the suggestions in your blog posts).